# Null objects while using Coalesce and duplicate values while joining

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jooq

```
[
  {
    "permissions": [
      {
        "name": "CREATE",
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "DELETE",
        "id": 4
      }
    ],
    "roles": [
      {
        "name": "ADMIN",
        "permission": [
          {
            "name": "CREATE",
            "id": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "UPDATE",
            "id": 2
          },
          {
            "name": "GET",
            "id": 3
          },
          {
            "name": "DELETE",
            "id": 4
          }
        ],
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "ADMIN",
        "permission": [
          {
            "name": "CREATE",
            "id": 1
          },
          {
            "name": "UPDATE",
            "id": 2
          },
          {
            "name": "GET",
            "id": 3
          },
          {
            "name": "DELETE",
            "id": 4
          }
        ],
        "id": 1
      }
    ],
    "id": 1,
    "username": "raj@100"
  },
  {
    "permissions": [
      {
        "name": null,
        "id": null
      }
    ],
    "roles": [
      {
        "name": "USER",
        "permission": [
          {
            "name": "GET",
            "id": 3
          }
        ],
        "id": 3
      }
    ],
    "id": 2,
    "username": "ram145"
  }
]
```

As you can see from the above output the in roles the ADMIN is repeated twice and in the second users has no permissions so he should have an empty array but the output is with the permission object with all its values empty

This is the jooq statement which is executed :

```
public Object findAllUsers(String role, String permission) {
        SelectOnConditionStep<Record1<JSON>> query = dslContext.select(
                jsonObject(
                    key("id").value(USER.ID),
                    key("fullName").value(USER.FULL_NAME),
                    key("username").value(USER.USERNAME),
                    key("email").value(USER.EMAIL),
                    key("mobile").value(USER.MOBILE),
                    key("isActive").value(USER.IS_ACTIVE),
                    key("lastLoggedIn").value(USER.LAST_LOGGED_IN),
                    key("profileImage").value(USER.PROFILE_IMAGE),
                    key("roles").value(
                        coalesce(
                            jsonArrayAgg(
                                jsonObject(
                                    key("id").value(ROLE.ID),
                                    key("name").value(ROLE.NAME),
                                    key("permission").value(
                                        coalesce(
                                            select(
                                                jsonArrayAgg(
                                                    jsonObject(
                                                        key("id").value(PERMISSION.ID),
                                                        key("name").value(PERMISSION.NAME)
                                                    )
                                                )
                                            ).from(ROLE_PERMISSION)
                                                .leftJoin(PERMISSION)
                                                .on(PERMISSION.ID.eq(ROLE_PERMISSION.PERMISSION_ID))
                                                .where(ROLE_PERMISSION.ROLE_ID.eq(ROLE.ID))
                                                .orderBy(PERMISSION.NAME.asc()),
                                            jsonArray()
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            ),
                            jsonArray()
                        )
                    ),
                    key("permissions").value(
                        coalesce(
                            jsonArrayAgg(
                                jsonObject(
                                    key("id").value(PERMISSION.ID),
                                    key("name").value(PERMISSION.NAME)
                                )
                            ),
                            jsonArray()
                        )
                    )
                )
            ).from(USER)
            .leftJoin(USER_ROLE).on(USER.ID.eq(USER_ROLE.USER_ID))
            .leftJoin(ROLE).on(USER_ROLE.ROLE_ID.eq(ROLE.ID))
            .leftJoin(USER_PERMISSION).on(USER.ID.eq(USER_PERMISSION.USER_ID))
            .leftJoin(PERMISSION).on(USER_PERMISSION.PERMISSION_ID.eq(PERMISSION.ID));
        if (role != null) {
            query.where(ROLE.NAME.eq(role));
        }
        if (permission != null) {
            query.where(PERMISSION.NAME.eq(role));
        }
        return query.groupBy(USER.ID)
            .orderBy(USER.ID.asc())
            .fetch().into(JSONObject.class);
    }
```

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why the duplicates?

Your join graph creates a cartesian product between the two "nested collections" `ROLE` and `PERMISSION`. You can't remove that cartesian product with `GROUP BY` alone, that works only if you join a single to-many relationship.

Instead, you can write subqueries like this (you already did this correctly for the `ROLE_PERMISSION` relationship):

```java
dslContext.select(jsonObject(
    key("id").value(USER.ID),
    key("username").value(USER.USERNAME),
    key("roles").value(coalesce(field(
        select(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(
            key("id").value(ROLE.ID),
            key("name").value(ROLE.NAME),
            key("permission").value(coalesce(field(
                select(coalesce(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(
                    key("id").value(PERMISSION.ID),
                    key("name").value(PERMISSION.NAME)
                )), jsonArray()))
                .from(ROLE_PERMISSION)
                .join(PERMISSION)
                .on(PERMISSION.ID.eq(ROLE_PERMISSION.PERMISSION_ID))
                .where(ROLE_PERMISSION.ROLE_ID.eq(ROLE.ID))
                .orderBy(PERMISSION.NAME.asc())
            ), jsonArray()))
        )))
        .from(USER_ROLE)
        .join(ROLE)
        .on(USER_ROLE.ROLE_ID.eq(ROLE.ID))
        .where(USER_ROLE.USER_ID.eq(USER.ID))
    ), jsonArray())),
    key("permissions").value(coalesce(field(
        select(coalesce(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(
            key("id").value(PERMISSION.ID),
            key("name").value(PERMISSION.NAME)
        )))
        .from(USER_PERMISSION)
        .join(PERMISSION)
        .on(USER_PERMISSION.PERMISSION_ID.eq(PERMISSION.ID))
        .where(USER_PERMISSION.USER_ID.eq(USER.ID))
    ), jsonArray()))
))
.from(USER)
.orderBy(USER.ID.asc())
.fetch().into(JSONObject.class);
```

#### Join vs semi join

After you edited your question to become a slightly different question, the point you were trying to make is that you want to filter the `USER` table by some `ROLE` or `PERMISSION` that they must have. You can't achieve this with `JOIN` alone (unless you're happy with the duplicates). The answer I gave doesn't change. If you're joining multiple to-many relationships, you'll get cartesian products.

So, instead, why not [`semi join` them](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/joined-tables/join-type-semi/)? Either with jOOQ's synthetic `SEMI JOIN` syntax, or manually using `EXISTS` or `IN`, e.g.

```java
.where(role != null
    ? exists(selectOne()
          .from(USER_ROLE)
          .where(USER_ROLE.role().NAME.eq(role))
      )
    : noCondition()
)
.and(permission != null
    ? exists(selectOne()
          .from(USER_PERMISSION)
          .where(USER_PERMISSION.permission().NAME.eq(permission))
      )
    : noCondition()
)
```

This is using the [implicit join syntax](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/), which is optional, but I think it does simplify your query.

Comment: I know I can do it easily with sub-queries but I have to query the users based on roles and permissions. Which I can not do when I write sub-queries. Once again see the code I have updated the code .

Comment: @SaiUttej: Well, I answered your question, which was why you got duplicate values. You can't join two to-many relationships and avoid those duplicates. You can, however, [semi-join them](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/joined-tables/join-type-semi/) (effectively using `EXISTS` or `IN`). I'll give an example in my answer

Comment: Is there is any thing like noCondition() for no limit and no offset too?

Comment: @SaiUttej: See https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2333